# Table of ParametricPlots crashes Kernel

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, memory

I can usually crash the Mathematica Kernel by using `Table` to generate a `List` of `ParametricPlot`s, as follows:

```
 testpara[α_] :=
 ParametricPlot[
  {
   {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]},
   {2 Cos[α] + Cos[θ], 
    2 Sin[α] + Sin[θ]},
   {r, 0}
   },
  {θ, 0, 2 π},
  {r, 1, 2},
  PlotRange -> 3,
  Frame -> False
  ]

Table[testpara[α], {α, 0, 2. π - π/36, π/36.}]
```

The current "high" number of plots, with a step size of π/36, crashes the Kernel every time. Starting with a large step size (eg. π/6) often works well on first execution, but also crashes if I execute the cell again. The smaller the step size (leading to a larger number of plots in the `List`), the higher the regularity of the Kernel crashes.

- Surely a list containing 12 ParametricPlots isn't too much?
- How can I prevent this crashing behavior?

(For example, is it something I can code differently, or do I need to change available memory in Options somewhere or ...?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem (V10.1, Win7-32).

Comment: Failed to reproduce also in 9.0.1, 8.0.4, 7.0.1.

Comment: I have the problem in v10.1.0 (OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite, Intel i7 2.2 GHz, 16GB ram).

Comment: @zentient Unfortunately (or fortunately perhaps?) I can't reproduce your crash either. I am using V10.1 on Win7-64bit. As an aside, `ParallelTable` shaves at least a couple of seconds off the execution time on my system. Is there any difference if you use that instead of `Table` in your case?

Comment: Confirmed w 10.1/linux.  If I change the `Table` to `Do` it runs through but any attempt to retain all the plots (`Reap/Sow` , `Append`, etc ) result in a kernel quit with no error message

Comment: Using an integer iterator  makes it work: `Table[testpara[ia  Pi/ 36.], {ia, 0, 71}]`.  Good practice anyway, but it still should work the way you have it.

Comment: I confirm the kernel crash with v10.1.0 but not with v9.0.1 (on OSX 10.9.5) !

Comment: @george2079 Your workaround does not work for me ... (v10.1.0,OSX)

Comment: When I run `ParallelTable`, I also consistently get the following error messages: `LinkObject::linkd` ,  `Kernels::read` ,  `LaunchKernels::clone`. `ParallelTable` does not cause the Kernel crash, while Table does (with the same arguments). @marcob : Running `ParallelTable` also improves time considerably!

Comment: `ParallelTable` gives me a slew of errors indicating kernels are quitting and beeing restarted, eg.  "Requeueing evaluations {63} assigned to KernelObject [21,local \
,<defunct>]."   (It does does complete though)

Comment: Failed to reproduce on OS X 10.10.3 mma 10.1 (i7-4980HQ, 16GB ram)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On further look, your `ParametricPlot` expression is a bit odd.  You have something like :

```
 ParametricPlot[{ f[t] , g[t] , h[r] } , {t,trange} , {r,rrange } .. ]
```

By supplying `ParametricPlot` with two independent variables it thinks you want to  plot regions, yet none of your functions depends on both variables.

Try this:

```
 testpara[\[Alpha]_] := Show[{
       ParametricPlot[{
           {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]},
           {2 Cos[\[Alpha]] + Cos[\[Theta]],2 Sin[\[Alpha]] + Sin[\[Theta]]}
                       }, {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]},
                          PlotRange -> 3, Frame -> False],
       ParametricPlot[{{r, 0}}, {r, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> 3,
           Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]}]
 Table[ testpara[\[Alpha]], {\[Alpha], 0, 2. \[Pi] - \[Pi]/36, [Pi]/36.}]
```

[image] ( Etc ... )

A more simple example in case  that doesn't make sense: This apparently works just fine

```
 ParametricPlot[ { r, r^2  } , {r, 0, 1}, {p, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

but looking close,

```
 Cases[ Normal@% , _Polygon , Infinity] // Length
```

> 3136

that curve is rendered as thousands of tiny degenerate polygons.

Of course having the kernel just shut down is never acceptable, but it least we can sort of see why.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[t, al];

set[t_, al_] := {{Cos[t], al + Sin[t]}, {2 Cos[al] + Cos[t], 2 Sin[al] + Sin[t]}, {al, t}};

ParametricPlot[set[t, al], {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, {al, 1, 2}, PlotRange -> All]

Table[set[1., al], {al, 0, 2. \[Pi] - \[Pi]/36, \[Pi]/36.}] // TableForm
```

Taking one parameter only in the Table, it works.

Comment: not sure what you mean to do , but this is a completely different figure.

Comment: As it is I tried to put in two parameters only, at first to avoiding a crash as given combination is too cramped.